# Need a host which supports OSQA

Tags: web-hosting, looking-for-hosting, django, python

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to find web hosting that meets my requirements?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/20838/how-to-find-web-hosting-that-meets-my-requirements)

Hi i'm looking to install OSQA and see how it goes I have a great niche which I think may work real well, but till I get a large enough audience I'd like to use shared hosting then move up to a dedicated or vps hosting...

Almost all hosts i've looked at don't support something OSQA needs

I need relatively cheap shared hosting with cpanel. Any recommendations?

It needs to support:

- Django
- Python markdown
- html5lib
- Python OpenId
- South

Answer (score 1):

You may be best setting yourself up with a VPS, rather than plunging for shared hosting. That way you can set it up exactly how you want. VPS's can be almost as cheap as decent shared hosting. It is a little more work to set up, but there are plenty of guides online.

Answer (score 0):

WebFaction meets all your requirements except CPanel.

They even have an install script that sets it up automatically.

https://wiki.webfaction.com/wiki/InstallScripts